# ReactJS : How to use "form" tag?

Tags: forms, reactjs, input, react-native

Hello everyone I'm trying to learn ReactJS and I would like to know why everybody is using  tag to build forms.

I mean when I use this code:

```
   import { TextInput, Form, View } from 'react-native'

   <Form onSubmit={this.onSubmit}>
    <TextInput/>
   </Form>
```

I got this error :

> Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components)
>   or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You
>   likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in.

Or when I use this code :

```
  import { TextInput, form, View } from 'react-native'

  render (){
    return (
        <View>
            <form onSubmit={this.onSubmit}>
                <TextInput/>
            </form>
        </View>
    );
  }
```

I got this error :

> Expected a component class, got [object Object].

I'm trying to fix and use a form but I'm mostly trying to understand how it works :)

Thank you for your time and your responses in advance.

Cheers

Comment: Pro tip: are you sure `react-native` is actually installed?

Comment: Yes I can use "real" components from react-native, I just thought that "form" was a component from react-native cause I saw a lot of code in stackoverflow speaks about <form> tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

React-Native doesn't actually contain a `Form` tag.

There are libraries such as [react-native-form-generator](https://github.com/MichaelCereda/react-native-form-generator) that provide similar functionality to what you are looking for.

Moreover, the error you're getting is trying to tell you exactly that - a class or function which defines a react component is expected where you specify a tag, but it was `undefined`, since there is no such component.

Comment: Ok I see, it's clear, I thought that there was a component for this. Anyway thank you for this explication and your time